# Create a function that takes a number num and returns each place value in the number

Tags: python

Create a function that takes a number num and returns each place value in the number.
Eg num_split(-434) ➞ [-400, -30, -4], num_split[59]->[50,9]

Comment: Hello. Did you read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)?

Comment: Yes, and it's fairly straightforward too! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to _make an honest attempt_, and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def num_split(num):
    num = str(num)
    num = [c for c in num]
    num = num[::-1]
    num_lis = []
    f = 1
    for i in range(len(num)):
        num_lis.append(int(num[i])*f)
        f *= 10
    return num_lis


print(num_split(59))
```

Comment: Answering homework questions or any question where the OP has not put in their effort at solving the problem, is discouraged on StackOverflow. Also, your output for `59` is `[9, 50]` instead of `[50, 9]`.

Comment: `return list(map(lambda x:x*[1,-1][num<0], reversed([int(x) * 10**i for i,x in enumerate(reversed((str(num)).strip('-')))])))`

Comment: @aneroid What is the criteria to determine whether this question is a homework question or not? Also, thanks for the insight!

Comment: @Matthias ...sheesh

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi _"Please write a program that does xyz"_ is a homework question, broadly speaking. The main point is: the OP put no **effort** into the question or attempting to solve it first - such as a function that doesn't quite work but at least **attempts** to. StackOverflow is a "we'll help" site not a "we'll do it all for you" site. (Yes, there are some high rep users who just answer any and all questions; that's a choice for to make after knowing what the general practice _should_ be.)